# I can't draw trees with X-bar theory

Tags: syntax

I'm taking Introduction to Syntax as an elective course in my department, English language teaching. On Tuesday, our instructor addressed X-bar theory and drawing trees with it. I couldn't understand it, though. When drawing a tree, I can't quite sense when to use the bar level. Whenever I draw a tree, I often tend to omit this level involuntarily as I can't quite grasp what the bar level is for. What would you suggest for me? I'm really on the verge of dropping this course even though I'm interested in linguistics.

Comment: Ask your teacher for more help!

Comment: https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/100357884082/how-to-draw-syntax-trees-part-1-so-you-asked

Comment: I agree with Greg Lee. If you can, stick with 'conventional' trees: the kind that have labels for functions and categories at each node.

Comment: Just curious, what textbook do you use, if any?

Comment: @AlexB. For assigned readings before the class, our class use Andrew Carnie's book  Syntax: A Generative Introduction.

Comment: That’s a good textbook imho. First, even though X-bar theory was abandoned a while ago, I think it’s still useful to understand its basic tenets and argumentation behind  it. To better help you, can you please share one of your “wrong” trees?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the principles of X-bar "theory".  I suggest using the examples of trees you have in your notes or your text as models for your own tree drawing.  Draw lots of trees.  Show your difficult cases to your instructor and ask whether he sees anything wrong.  Treat the matter as an art, not a science.

I don't understand X-bar theory, either.  But I'm not sure there is anything there to understand, other than an arbitrary notation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24367)

Comment: @bytebuster, I have answered the only question that was asked: "What would you suggest for me?"